# Which directories get affected by "Linux PCI-DSS patch updates" and "Kernel update"

Tags: redhat, pci-dss

To achieve the PCI-DSS compliance, Company should apply all OS patching in monthly bases.

However, these patches affect the File Integrity monitoring, for example

/etc/bin /etc/include and much more directories.

My question is, how to know which directories get affected by a specific Patch?

Thanks in advance.